# not able to verify ssl-certificate from client side using any of python requests, httplib/httplib2, urllib/urlib2

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, httplib

this question is duplicate. but i am still asking because i am not finding any solution from given answers. so guys don't make it duplicate, instead help me to solve this problem.

i am running my server as https using bottle(paste). when trying to access from java and postman , it's verifying correctly and response coming.

versions used :
python 2.7.13

> > > requests.**version**
> > >       '2.11.1'
> > >       import cryptography
> > >       cryptography.**version**
> > >       '2.1.3'
> > >       import OpenSSL
> > >       OpenSSL.**version**
> > >       '17.3.0'

but unfortunately when trying to access from python modules - it's throwing issue. ?

```
requests.post(url, verify=_certfile, proxies=proxies) #tried #failed to verify certificate

urllib2.urlopen(url, data=data, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=context)  #tried #failed to verify certificate

import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
headers, content = http.request(url, "POST", body=data, headers=headers)#tried #failed to verify certificate

httplib.HTTPSConnection(host='10.201.41.50', port=8018, key_file=key_file, cert_file=cert_file, strict=None, context=context) #tried #failed to verify certificate
```

and my server is running using paste server using bottle framework.

```
ssl_cxt = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
...
...
ssl_cxt.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_cb)
paste.httpserver.serve(app, host=IP, port=PORT, server_version=" ", ssl_context=ssl_cxt)
```

issues i am facing (different with each lib)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2947)
```

============

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate 
verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

  File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
  File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
  File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
  self.connect()
  File "Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1262, in connect
  self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to solve using urllib2, socket and ssl. i am able to hit the server. i tried with .pkcs12 but seems urllib2 expects only .pem files. so will advice try to create client certificate with .pem extension specifically when you try to access from python.

```
import ssl
import socket
import urllib2
import json


url = "https://localhost:port/hello/"

_certfile_pem = "ssl_client.pem"
key_file = "ssl_key.pem"
cert_file = "ssl_cert.pem"

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
data = {}

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_file, keyfile=key_file)
context.load_verify_locations(_certfile_pem)
context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))  # 
socket overwrite required.

try:
    req = urllib2.Request(url,data=json.dumps(data))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, context=context)
    content = response.read()
    print content
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    content = e.read()
    print "HTTPError : ", e
```